# What I must change to make this code listen on UDP port?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, server, udp, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to create a server Windows Form application but my code throw a 0x80004005 error when call the Listen method.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub StartUdpReceiveThread(ByVal Puerto As Integer)
    If Not UdpOpen Then
        Try
           permission = New SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Udp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts)

            sListener = Nothing

            permission.Demand()

            'Dim ipHost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("")

            Dim ipAddr As IPAddress =  IPAddress.Any

            ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipAddr, CInt(Me.PuertoEscuchaLbl.Text))

            'sListener = New Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Unknown, ProtocolType.Udp)
            sListener = New Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.UDP)

            ' Associates a Socket with a local endpoint 
            sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint)

            sListener.Listen(5)

            ' Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
            Dim aCallback As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback)
            sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener)

            PrintLog("Server listening on " & ipEndPoint.Address.ToString & " port: " & ipEndPoint.Port)

            UdpOpen = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
CallBack method
    Public Sub AcceptCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim listener As Socket = Nothing

```
    ' A new Socket to handle remote host communication 
    Dim handler As Socket = Nothing
    Try
        ' Receiving byte array 
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
        ' Get Listening Socket object 
        listener = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)'<-- Here raises an error
        ' Create a new socket 
        handler = listener.EndAccept(ar)

        handler.NoDelay = False

        ' Creates one object array for passing data 
        Dim obj As Object() = New Object(1) {}
        obj(0) = buffer
        obj(1) = handler

        handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), obj)

        ' Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
        Dim aCallback As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback)
        listener.BeginAccept(aCallback, listener)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just pick the first IP address in `IPHostEntry.AddressList` but search the array for an IPv4 address. See the example on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I change the line that defines ipAddr variable to Dim ipAddr As IPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1") and seems to work but opens a TCP port and I need an UDP port. :(

Comment: Even when using `SocketType.Dgram` and `ProtocolType.UDP`?

Comment: Thanks!, I changed and seems to work until I call the Listen method and raises an error because the Listen method is no available for UDP. I read some on internet and seems like the process to put a socket in listen mode for UDP is different than TCP, I make this code based on a TCP server. Now I'm trying with BeginAccept method instead but on the CallBack raises an error because the EndAccept method does not return an asyncResult.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean that I tried with BeginAccept and doesn't work, now I'm trying with BeginConnect. I'm adding the CallBack code to this post